# Graphs won't overlap eachother

Tags: excel, vba

I have X amount of graphs where X is always an even number. Every series shows up as two graphs. One line graph and a Xy Scatter plot. The problem is that the graphs are separated, one to the left, one to the right. I want them to overlap so the points from the Scatter plot shows where the lines break. This is what I want:
[image]

But this is what I get:
[image]

By the way, these are two different graphs. One shows dates, the other weeks. The one with dates work, the week one doesn't.

This is the code concerning the week graph:

```
With myChart.Chart
.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = actualdateweek

'actualdateweek is an array with week numbers like 21,22 and so on

.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

If LineGraph = True Then
.SeriesCollection(i).Values = actualdata
.SeriesCollection(i).ChartType = xlLine
.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.Visible = msoTrue
.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(ColorR(i - iModifier - 1), ColorG(i - iModifier - 1), ColorB(i - iModifier - 1))

'actualdata is an array with all the data

elseif XyScatterPlot = True Then
.SeriesCollection(i).Values = actualdata
.SeriesCollection(i).ChartType = xlXYScatter
.SeriesCollection(i).MarkerStyle = xlMarkerStyleSquare
.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(ColorR(i - iModifier - 1), ColorG(i - iModifier - 1), ColorB(i - iModifier - 1))
.SeriesCollection(i).MarkerForegroundColorIndex = -4142
End If

.SeriesCollection(i).AxisGroup = 1

Next i
End With
```

The graphs are added in turns. First a data series (the actualdata array) is added as a line graph. Then the same data series is added but as a scatter plot. Then the data series changes and it all repeats. So it's like

```
seriescollection(1).XValues = array filled with week numbers
seriescollection(1).Values = Data series 1
seriescollection(1).ChartType = xlLine

seriescollection(2).XValues = array filled with week numbers
seriescollection(2).Values = Data series 1
seriescollection(2).ChartType = xlXYScatter

seriescollection(3).XValues = array filled with week numbers
seriescollection(3).Values = Data series 2
seriescollection(3).ChartType = xlLine

seriescollection(4).XValues = array filled with week numbers
seriescollection(4).Values = Data series 2
seriescollection(4).ChartType = xlXYScatter
```

This is what the first graph looks like:
[image]

Then when the data to the second graph is added:

```
.SeriesCollection(i).Values = actualdata
```

[image]

Then the second graph is changed into a scatter plot:

```
.SeriesCollection(i).ChartType = xlXYScatter
```

[image]

Then an axis group is assigned:

```
.SeriesCollection(i).AxisGroup = 1
```

[image]

Anyone have an idea what is happening?

*edit*
Ok problem solved I guess...
By removing the X value for the XYScatterPlot it aligned with the Line Graph.

This line:
`.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = actualdateweek`

Comment: Think you would need to set the chart to `Combo` first, then specify the series types.

Comment: How do I do that? I googled but didn't understand.

Comment: Ok I don't understand why, but by not setting a XValue to the Scatter plot graph it some how aligned with the Line graph. So I guess problem is solved, even though I don't now why!

Comment: Think of it as pre-setting the chart space before loading the series to it.